# PyPy on Windows XP

Tags: python, windows-xp, compatibility, pypy

What is the **last** version of **PyPy** to be compatible with Windows XP?

Their latest version is not.

https://downloads.python.org/pypy/pypy3.7-v7.3.2-win32.zip

PyPy releases are available here, but which one to choose?

https://downloads.python.org/pypy/

Comment: Windows XP's support ended 2014. Accordingly to https://www.python.org/doc/versions 3.4.X was released that time.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer:  Apparently PyPy maintained support for Windows XP longer than did CPython. I am able to run PyPy version 5.10.1, which was released in 2018.